# Как лучше всего сделать так, чтобы нельзя было вводить одинаковые цифры при вводе?

Tags: java, массивы

Как лучше всего сделать, чтобы нельзя было вводить одинаковые цифры при вводе?

```
public int fiveNumbers = 1;
public String[] nForBingo = new String[5];
public int[] randomNumbersBingo = new int[70];
public boolean win = false;
public int i = 0;
public int chooseNumber = 0;
public int j = 0;
public boolean checkCreatedBingo = false;
public int numbersInBrackets = 0;
public int allNumbers = 0;
public int option;

public void run() {
    while (!win) {
        BINGO();

    }
}

public int BINGO() {
    System.out.println(
                         "\n************************ * BINGO ************************\n" +
                    "* 1) Create a Bingo card\n" +
                    "* 2) Draw a number\n" +
                    "* 3) Check Bingo card\n" +
                    "* 9) Exit \n*********************************************************");
    if (option == 9) {
        win = true;
        return -1;
    }
    System.out.print("Select a menu option: ");
    option = scan.nextInt();
    if (option == 1) {
        return createBingo();
    } else if (option == 2) {
        return drawNumber();
    } else if (option == 3) {
        return checkBingoCard();
    } else if (option == 9) {
        win = true;
        return -1;
    }

    return BINGO();
}

public int createBingo() {

    for (; i < nForBingo.length; ) {
        System.out.print("Enter a value for field " + fiveNumbers + ": ");
        nForBingo[i] = scan.next();
        if (chooseNumber > 20) {
            System.out.println("The entered value is too high! All values must be between 0 and 20.");
            return createBingo();
        } else if (chooseNumber < 0) {
            System.out.println("The entered value is too low! All values must be between 0 and 20.");
            return createBingo();
        } else {
            i++;
            fiveNumbers++;

        }
    }
    checkCreatedBingo = true;
    return BINGO();
}

public int drawNumber() {
    if (!checkCreatedBingo) {
        System.out.println("You must first create a Bingo card before drawing a number!");
        return BINGO();
    } else {
        randomNumbersBingo[j] = ((int) (Math.random() * 20));
        System.out.println("A number is drawn! The ball reads the number: " + randomNumbersBingo[j] + "!");
        System.out.print("[");
        for (i = 0; i < nForBingo.length; i++) {

            if (nForBingo[i].equals(String.valueOf(randomNumbersBingo[j]))) {
                numbersInBrackets++;
                nForBingo[i] = "(" + nForBingo[i] + ")";
            }

            System.out.print(nForBingo[i]);
            if (i < 4) {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }

        }
        System.out.println("]");
        allNumbers++;
        if (numbersInBrackets == 5) {
            System.out.println("BINGO! All numbers are marked in " + allNumbers + " turns.");
            option = 9;

            return BINGO();
        }
        return BINGO();
    }
}

public int checkBingoCard() {
    if (checkCreatedBingo) {
        System.out.print("Your Bingo cart: [ ");
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            System.out.print(randomNumbersBingo[j]);
            if (j < 4) {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(" ]");
        if (numbersInBrackets != 4) {
            System.out.println("Unfortunately you don’t have Bingo card yet!");
        } else if (numbersInBrackets == 4) {
            System.out.println("BINGO! All numbers are marked in " + allNumbers + " turns.");
        }
    }else {

        System.out.println("You must first create a Bingo card!");

    }
    return BINGO();
}
```

Comment: как лучше всего сделать чтобы нельзя было вводить одинаковые цыфры при вооде

Answer (score 4):

Вам потребуется хранить в некоторой структуре введенные цифры. Эффективней всего будет использовать [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) (множество) из Java Collections API. 
В двух словах, интерфейс Set хранит в себе уникальные элементы и позволяет производить операции добавления\удаления\проверки на существование крайне быстро (в зависимости от реализации). Примеры:

```
//Создаём новое множество и инициализируем стартовыми значениями.
//Т. к. множество хранит лишь уникальные значения, в set будут содержаться {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2));

System.out.println(set.contains(3));//Проверяем, содержиться ли значение в множестве
System.out.println(set.contains(6));
```

Из плюсов такого решения: простота использования и скорость. Из минусов: большой оверхед по памяти.

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать массив с значениями которые уже ввел. И перед вводом нового проверять: есть ли такое число в массиве. Если есть, то ищем новое число. Иначе, кладем значение в наш массив и продолжаем логику программы.

Comment: Set рациональнее